# How can I change a sphere's radius with a Python script?

Tags: python, scripting

I have been trying to write a script that generates pictures of sphere packing's given positions and radii's that are publication quality.  The most helpful post I found was here:
https://gskielian.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/creating-a-red-sphere-in-blender-with-python/  .

From this post I have been able to generate multiple spheres in blender with different coordinates for their centers.  What I haven't been able to do from this code is adjust their radii.  I thought that setting the radii for a sphere would be found in this portion of the code:

```
red = makeMaterial(‘Red’,(1,0,0),(1,1,1),1)
origin = (0,0,0)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(location=origin)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(1,0,0))
setMaterial(bpy.context.object, red)
```

But I've tried to adjust almost everything in that line of code with no use.  I'm hoping that someone can help me make adjustments to the linked code such that it generates a sphere of a specific radii, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, the least complicated approach is probably this:

```
import bpy

properties = [
   [[-2, 0, 0], 0.2],
   [[-1, 0, 0], 0.3],
   [[+0, 0, 0], 0.4],
   [[+1, 0, 0], 0.5],
   [[+2, 0, 0], 0.6]
]

# [co]ordinate, and [r]adius 
for co, r in properties:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(segments=34, size=r, location=co)
```

[image]

See the [documentation for UV Sphere](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=primitive#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add)

Depending on scene complexity other approaches will make more sense.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much for your speedy and "brain-dead" response, it is much better than the method I linked!

Comment: @mikervdn that's quite alright, welcome to the community!